# How to properly configure a FTPconnection with Windows Azure Server.?

Tags: windows, azure, ftp, azure-virtual-machine, filezilla

I'm new to Windows Azure Server configurations, and I'm trying to configure the FTP Connection. But when I access the Server with FileZilla it doesn't work. What am I doing wrong here?

I'm using IIS with FTP Server Roles installed.

**Following is the error log from FileZilla**

```
Status: Resolving address of AZR-SRV-map01.cloudapp.net
Status: Connecting to 52.187.64.207:990...
Status: Connection established, initializing TLS...
Status: Verifying certificate...
Status: TLS connection established, waiting for welcome message...
Status: Logged in
Status: Retrieving directory listing...
Command:    PWD
Response:   257 "/" is current directory.
Command:    TYPE I
Response:   200 Type set to I.
Command:    PASV
Response:   227 Entering Passive Mode (52,187,64,207,195,237).
Command:    LIST
Response:   150 Opening BINARY mode data connection.
Error:  Connection timed out after 20 seconds of inactivity
Error:  Failed to retrieve directory listing
Status: Disconnected from server
```

I also tried the following steps in configuring the FTP Connection...
**Here the endpoints have being configured from the Azure Portal.**
[image]

**This is how I published the FTP Site**


[image]
[image]

**Configured the FTP Firewall Support with the Azure Server Public IP**
[image]

And **enabled the firewall outbound and inbound rules**..
[image]

After completing all the steps, I restarted the Microsoft FTP Service, but the problem still exists.

Answer (score 3):

For now, we **can't** configure a active mode FTP on Azure VM. we should configure data channel port range in FTP Firewall Support, FTP work in **passive mode**. For example, we can use 10000-10010 ports as the data channel port range. Also, we should add ports to VM's **endpoints** and add then to VM's **firewall** inbound rules. 
[image]
By the way, although the windows firewall seems to allow all traffic that’s required, we also need to enable **stateful FTP filtering** on the firewall:

```
netsh advfirewall set global StatefulFtp enable
```

Then restart the FTP windows service and we should be up and running:

```
net stop ftpsvc
net start ftpsvc
```

Here a case similar as you, please refer to [it](https://serverfault.com/questions/822715/how-to-access-my-ftp-sever-over-the-internet/822819#822819).

Comment: Please let me know if you would like further assistance:)